# angular 7 service stock HttpClient on varibale in component ts

Tags: angular, promise

In result i get undefined ??
I use contact Api , in service is get data on component html but when i console the result i get undefined.

```
  element: any ;
  constructor(private service: BlockService) { }
   ngOnInit() {
        this.service.getSource().subscribe(async data=> {
        console.log(data)
        return  this.element  = await data
      })
    console.log(this.element )
  }
```

Comment: You log the data before you await it.

Comment: remove async and await. And whatever you want to do after data fetched, do it inside subscribe block.

Comment: even after i remove steel undefined

Comment: @HardikPatel => did mean there is no way to get data outside the subscribe

Comment: I first need to understand your case why you require data outside subscribe function.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need the `async` and the `await` key words. The service is async by default

```
  element: any;
  constructor(private service: BlockService) {}
  ngOnInit() {
    this.service.getSource().subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data); // will log the data
      this.element = data;
    });
    console.log(this.element) // will log null/undefined.
  }
```

**EDIT:**

Think of the subscription happening a tick later in the run time. If we have a timeline represented by numbers, the execution of code will happen more or less like this:

1. construtor code
2. ngOnInit code
3. Starting subscription (waiting for response)
4. console.log('this.element').
5. Got the response from the subscription, so we get the data, and
   this.element is set.

Comment: yes there is any explanation why data get null even we know that service is async !!?

Comment: It will be null/undefined because the code inside the subscription will be run one tick after the rest of the code, so `this.element` is not initialized yet.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  element: any ;
  constructor(private service: BlockService) { }
   ngOnInit() {
        this.service.getSource().subscribe(data=> {
        console.log(data);
        this.element  = data;
        someMethod();
      })
  }
  someMethod(){
   //here you can use this.element data
  }
```

Comment: I have edited the code check once whether this is what you required

Comment: yes i understand the code but in my case is so difficult to use it like that

Comment: can you add it in stackblitz...so that i can help you

Answer (score 0):

You may can use

```
  element: any;
  constructor(private service: BlockService) { }
  async ngOnInit() {
    this.element = await this.service.getSource().toPromise();
    console.log(this.element)
  }
```

Comment: yuh i have erreur core.js:15723 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: this.service.getSource(...).toPromise is not a function

Answer (score 0):

> This is not how Observer pattern works you have to subscribe to observer data stream to fetch data. and you cannot grab data without subscribing it!

So there is no use of `async` or `await` operator inside of subscription!

in this scenario you can have variable outside of block scope and assign the value after subscribing the observer

```js
export class MyComponent {

  dataToPopulate: any = null;

  constructor(private service: BlockService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.service.subscribe(
      data => dataToPopulate = {...data}, // for response 200 OK

      error => console.log(error), // handle network error here {400 or 500 etc}

      () => console.log(this.dataToPopulate) // complete callback hook
    )
  }

}
```

**Pro tip**: Unsubscribe the subscription on component destroy hook to avoid any memory leak

There is another way to convert Observable to Promise `toPromise` and use `async` and `await` operator. But for network calls you need `try` `catch` blocks around these statements to detect service error responses like `400` or `500`